# Point to Many Items

Tags: database-design

I have a point file showing locations of many warehouses. But I want to expand this inventory to show the many items each of these warehouses store and sell. The items fall into four categories: electrical, hardware, lumber and plumbing.

In order to link the id number of the point shape file, I was initially thinking that I would create a lookup table housing the four categories. But from that point, I also need to link that lookup table to list of hundreds of items that fall within each of these categories.

What is the best way to link the point file to the category lookup table and then to the list of products that fall within those categories?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a database model similar to this:

[image]

*(Non-key attributes omitted for brevity.)*

There is a many-to-many relationship between warehouses and items (implemented through the junction table WAREHOUSE_ITEM). There is also a one-to-many relationship between categories and items.